# Isn't this invention half-century old?

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, us20100073978

The patent us 2010/0073978 is clearly NOT an invention of a German company.
To see how it had been used in volt meters in 1998, visit:
http://www.chipinfo.ru/literature/radio/199801/p29.html

To have the material proof of the working bipolar transistor rectifier bridge exactly as shown on patent drawings, I can provide a power supply of my grandfather's radio, made in 1965. The synchronous rectifiers on germanium transistors were especially efficient at the time.

The us20100073978 is a common knowledge and not an invention of the 21st century.

Answer (score 2):

This application was rejected and ended up going abandoned in 2011 (you can look it up in Public PAIR at the USPTO). The primary reference used against it was [US 3,434034](https://www.google.com/patents/US3434034) - A Universal AC or DC to DC converter - by Hewlett Packard (HP) in 1967.

Answer (score 0):

US20100073938 is just an application for patent, it is not granted as patent yet. See here http://www.google.com/patents/US20100073978

Under publication type you can see it is just application. For example, see this granted patent:
https://www.google.com/patents/US5834678

You can see under publication it is grant